# How do I stop Notepad++ to stop asking for XSD files?

Tags: notepad++

*Every time* I open or save an XML-formatted file (`.xml`, `.config`, etc.) in Notepad++, it asks for an XSD.  I don't have one, and I have no need for one.

How can I make Notepad++ stop asking.  That dialog is incredibly annoying.

Comment: Fiddle with the `Plugins -> XML Tools` options?

Comment: @AlexK. my first impression of your comment was, "That doesn't really help." But after looking, I found `Enable auto-validation`.  List as answer and you get credit, good sir.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Plugins -> XML Tools -> Enable Auto Validation

Notepad++ 7.4.2

Windows 7

Comment: To further clarify for future readers: I *deselected* Enable Auto Validation to get the popup to stop. Notepad ++ v.7.5.1, Windows 10